# Jquery and CSS preforming strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've this section of code (I'll point out where I'm confused, just added that huge wall to incase anyone wanted to really dig in).

anyway, the behaviour is to display these boxes, when you click on a box, the box expands, and displays more information.  this works 70% of the time, however, it seems when an image is not chached, when you click the box again to minimize it, it starts to minimize, then pops back out.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the line: `if($(this)[0].style.width == '70%'){`

If this isn't enough, feel free to ask, and if you want to attempt to replicate the issue:

http://newgameplus.nikuai.net/

Try searching a few games, and clicking on the results.  (That's only if what I"m saying isn't making sense though)

Thank you.

```
$container.on("click", ".box", function (event) {
    var description;
    var user_id;
    var org_img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    if ($(this)[0].style.width == '70%') {
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", org_img);
        $(this).css('width', '18%');
        $(this).find(".resultData").fadeOut('slow');
        $container.masonry('reload');
    } else {
        var me = this;
        value['name'] = $(me).find("p").html();
        oldImage = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/php/fetchResultsData.php',
            data: {
                action: value
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                description = data[0][2];

                for (var i = 0; i < $test.length; i++) {
                    if ($test[i][1][2]['name'] == value['name']) {
                        pos = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $(me).find("img").attr("src", data[0][4]);
                $(me).css('width', '70%');

                $(me).append("\
                                        <div class='resultData'>\
                                            <div class='resultName'>" + value['name'] + "</div>\
                                            <div class='resultDesc'>" + description + "</div>\
                                            <div class='reasonDataTitle'> Similar tropes between this game and the searched games </div>\
                                            <div class='reasonData'>" + $test[pos][4] + "</div>\
                                            <div class='wikiLink'><a href='http://wikipedia.org/wiki/" + value['name'] + "'>Wikipedia</a></div>\
                                            <div class='resultLike'></div>\
                                        </div>");
                value['clicked'] = 0;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'scripts/php/userProfile.php',
                    data: {
                        action: value
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (profileData) {
                        if (profileData == 'alreadyAdded') {
                            $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('un-Favourite');
                        } else if (profileData == 'notLoggedIn') {
                            $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('Login to add');
                        } else {
                            $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('Favourite?');
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(me).on("click", '.resultLike', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation()
                    value['clicked'] = 1;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'scripts/php/userProfile.php',
                        data: {
                            action: value
                        },
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (profileData) {
                            if (profileData == 'removed') {
                                $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('Favourite?');
                            } else if (profileData == 'notLoggedIn') {
                                $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('Login to add');
                            } else {
                                $(me).children('.resultData').children('.resultLike').html('un-Favourite');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                $container.masonry('reload');
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Holy mother of all scripts! My first recommendation would be to break that puppy up. Independent functions are a hell of a lot easier to debug than one giant master function.

Comment: The more code you post, the more you have to care about proper formatting, otherwise it gets *really* messy.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Hahah, though I'm a fan of breaking things up, I feel I needed the help on all of it.  I can't help but think I"m abusing jquery and css the way I'm using it, so I wanted to be safe and throw it all in here.

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly sure where the debugging would begin, because it works MOST of the time, just seems to break during a non-cached image.

Comment: @Adola Not abusing exactly, but flouting the rules. Your implementation would certainly benefit from a simple templating language. You could also seperate your AJAX success events into separate functions. As for your problem, try assigning a size to your image object. It's probably crapping out because the uncached image doesn't know what size to render itself as.

Comment: Unless I'm being really oblivious to the obvious answer here; how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect there's a race condition in your effects code. jQuery effects run asynchronously, so `$container.masonry('reload')` will get called when `fadeOut` starts rather than after it's finished. If the jQuery Masonry plugin affects the display of any blocks you're fading out (and its documentation indicates that's highly possible), that race condition of both functions running at once will cancel the first one out.

To work around this, try running the Masonry reload in a callback function to `fadeOut`, like so:

```
$(this).find(".resultData").fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $container.masonry('reload');
});
```

The reason it happens only sometimes is based on the speed of how things are loading, which would explain why it only happens when certain assets aren't cached.

Comment: I didn't quite take this path to solve it, but the reasoning is the same, so I gave you the answer ;]